# Testing RxJava2 doOnComplete()

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, rx-java2

As you can see from the code below, I am attempting to test the behavior of the `doOnComplete()` call occurring within my repository. However, when I mock the injected dependency of my client where I return items using `Observable.just()`, the `doOnComplete()` is no longer invoked. I believe this is intentional as per RxJava2. I'm unsure as to how to work around this.

```
@Singleton
public class Repository {
    private SomeNetworkClient client;
    private SomeCache cache;

    @Inject
    public Repository(SomeNetworkClient client, SomeCache cache) {
        this.client = client;
        this.cache = cache;
    }

    public Observable<SomeItem> getSomeItem() {
        return client.getSomeItem()
                .doOnComplete(() -> cache.doThisOnComplete())
                .doOnError(throwable -> someError);
    }
}

public class RepositoryTest {
    private Repository testedRepository;
    @Mock
    SomeNetworkClient client;
    @Mock
    SomeCache cache;
    @Mock
    SomeItem someItem;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        testedRepository = new Repository(client, cache);
        when(client.getSomeItem())
            .thenReturn(Observable.just(someItem));
    }

    @Test
    public void thisTestFails() {
        testedRepository.getSomeItem().blockingFirst();
        // This fails because it appears that mocking with
        // Observable.just() makes doOnComplete() not be invoked.
        verify(cache.doThisOnComplete());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in you code is, that [`blockingFirst()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#blockingFirst()) won't care to listen for complete event to happen. It will immediately return the first item from the stream and [dispose from observable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/d3455d0c9d57d522c31b5c25af83e8f2b8df12b6/src/main/java/io/reactivex/internal/observers/BlockingFirstObserver.java#L27).

Instead, you may perform assertion this way:

```
    testedRepository
            .getSomeItem()
            .test()
            .assertComplete()
```